# Create cron group and assign it to a custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, crontab, magento-cron

As the title suggests, how can I create a cron group and assign it to the custom module in magento 1??

Comment: means you want to  create cron run for custom extension?

Comment: Yes but I want that it works with an its cron groups.